# Change value of same field on multiple objects - JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have an object on my scope, `the_data`, which has multiple objects inside it.

One object, `important_entries` has a list of objects inside it.

The objects inside `important_entries` all have a specific field I want to change - `field_I_want_to_change`. The name of each of these objects is it's Id.

What I want to do is iterate over the `important_entries` object and for each object in it, change the value of each  `field_I_want_to_change` field.

Could someone possibly give me some pointers as to how best to accomplish this? I have access to the underscore library, if that can be of any use.

Here is a rough blueprint of my `the_data` object, I apologise for any syntax errors.

```
the_data : {
    some_data : {},
    some_data : {},
    important_entries: {
        xxxccc : {
            field_I_want_to_change: 'some data'
        },
        cccfff : {
            field_I_want_to_change: 'some data'
        },
        tttyyy : {
            field_I_want_to_change: 'some data'
        },
    },
    some_data : {},
    some_data : {}
}
```

Comment: What did you try? (Underscore seems like a good first step)

Comment: @doldt if I have a single object in 'important_entries', it's not a problem. Just when there are multiple objects I trip up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you [loop through javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)  and change the field?

```
p = the_data['important_entries'];
for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        p[key].field_I_want_to_change = 'some data';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the underscore lib

```
var thedata =  {
    some_data : {},
    some_data : {},
    important_entries: {
        xxxccc : {
            field_I_want_to_change: 'some data'
        },
        cccfff : {
            field_I_want_to_change: 'some data'
        },
        tttyyy : {
            field_I_want_to_change: 'some data'
        },
    },
    some_data : {},
    some_data : {}
}

 _.each(thedata.important_entries, function(entry) {
    entry.field_I_want_to_change = "new calue"
 })
```

If you are not sure if the "field_I_want_to_change" object exists always, through in a small check before with `_.has`